# Code error when called from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have written some code to link 3 workbooks that I use on a daily basis and automate some information transfer between the 3. The first contains information that is copied and pasted into the second in a relevant format by some code I have written. Within this second sheet there is some code, written by someone much more advanced than me who has now left, which reformats the information and pastes it into a third workbook. When run independently this macro in the second workbook works perfectly. However when I try to call it using my own code (stored in the first workbook) it doesn't work properly. This is where I think it is going wrong: (this is the codes in the second workbook which should create the third workbook)

```
Public Sub ExportOpenlinkDeals()

...

Set objWbk = ThisWorkbook
Set objWS = objWbk.Worksheets("SwapTrades")

Set objWbkOut = Application.Workbooks.Add
Set objWSOut = objWbkOut.Worksheets(1)

SetOpenLinkHeader objWSOut
```

If I stop my  code before it calls this macro from the second workbook and press the button for the above macro. If I ask my code to run it it doesn't create a new workbook but instead overwrites the headers in the 2nd workbook with the ones that should go in the third (ie performs SetOpenlinkHeader on the workbook that contains the macro being called rather than in a new one, which it just doesn't seem to create).

I call the macro that includes the above code using Application.Run "Workbookname.xls!Subname".

In case it is relevant SetOpenlinkHeader is a Private Sub and the code I use to call this (called Hedge if that helps communication) is just declared as Sub not public or private.

The code for SetOpenlinkHeader is:

```
Private Sub SetOpenLinkHeader(objWS As Worksheet)
With objWS
    .Range("A1").Value2 = "Type"
    .Range("B1").Value2 = "Trader id"
    .Range("C1").Value2 = "Trader location"
    .Range("D1").Value2 = "Chain"
    .Range("E1").Value2 = "Buy/sell"
    .Range("F1").Value2 = "Grade"
    .Range("G1").Value2 = "Internal Legal entity"
    .Range("H1").Value2 = "Month"
    .Range("I1").Value2 = "Year"
    .Range("J1").Value2 = "Put/Call"
    .Range("K1").Value2 = "Strike"
    .Range("L1").Value2 = "Quantity Lots Required"
    .Range("M1").Value2 = "Order type"
    .Range("N1").Value2 = "Executing broker"
    .Range("O1").Value2 = "Clearing broker"
    .Range("P1").Value2 = "Quantity Lots Filled"
    .Range("Q1").Value2 = "Price"
    .Range("R1").Value2 = "Electronic market flag"
    .Range("S1").Value2 = "EFP Deal Reference"
    .Range("T1").Value2 = "External legal entity"
    .Range("U1").Value2 = "Cross Entity Flag"
    .Range("V1").Value2 = "Balmo Day"
    .Range("W1").Value2 = "Trad Date"
    .Range("X1").Value2 = "UTI"
End With
End Sub
```

I have tried making the private sub public, changing ThisWorkbook to the specific workbook name and changing the order of the syntax around creating the new workbook,none of which have changed the result - please help!

I can't put a copy of this anywhere for confidentiality reasons but will provide more info on request!

Comment: What is the error message, and which line raises the error?  If the code which produces the error is not included in your Q (it does not appear to be), please revise your Q to include that information.  It's impossible to troubleshoot otherwise...

Comment: I don't get an error message, the code completes it just does so incorrectly - rather than opening a new worksheet and adding headers to it (ie running SetOpenlinkHeader on the new worksheet) it just adds the headers to the current sheet for some reason. This only happens when I call the code from my own macro.

Comment: Well I think we need to see the code for `SetOpenLinkHeader`...

Comment: @David Zemens I have added the code for that sub above. I'm new to this but it does seem that it is going wrong before that point because the new sheet isn't created for SetOpenlinkHeader to be run on but I could be wrong - I haven't been able to step through this section when calling it from my code (is there a way to do this, incidentally? I can only step through my own code and not the code it is calling) and as I said it all works fine when this code is run independently.

Comment: See [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) for tips on debugging including setting breakpoints and stepping through code using F8.

Comment: **This code is in the 2nd sheet and should create the 3rd sheet.** No, it creates a *new workbook*, not a new sheet.  Are you confusing the term "sheet" and "workbook"?  You mention multiple times about the various "sheets" -- are they all worksheets in a single file?

Comment: BTW, it's still very difficult to give you much assistance. Without seeing the flow of your code, what's calling what and in what sequence, it's hard to say what your problem might be...  How is `ExportOpenLinks` invoked?

Comment: Sorry yes I am saying sheet when I eman workbook - there are 3 workbooks. Exportopenlinks is invoked using Application.Run . thanks for the link - I know how to use F8 to step through code it just doesn't seem to allow you to step through a macro you call within your code when that macro is stored in another workbook.

Comment: **Exportopenlinks is invoked using Application.Run** From **WHERE**?  I should not have to ask you this many questions... If you cannot share your full code -- or at least a minimum amount of code required for others to replicate your problem condition -- it is unlikely you're going to get any assistance.

Comment: I am brand new to this and doing my best - this is my first ever post (and in my defense some of the info you have requested was included above, though it may not have been very clear to you and I apologise for that). Exportopenlink is invoked from the code in the first worksheet - the sub there is called hedge. perhaps this will help:

Worksheet 1 - includes the sub Hedge which calls ExportOpenlinkDeals
Worksheet 2 - includes both ExportOpenlinkDeals and SetOpenlinkHeader. ExportOpenlinkdeals calls SetOpenlinkHeader. ExportOpenlinkDeals creates Workbook 3 when it works correctly.

Comment: Doesn't it seem easier to just put all of the code in a single workbook? At least that way, you may be able to debug it a little more easily (if you can't step through the code as-is).  Why are your macros scattered across multiple workbooks?  And, why not leverage a *template* file, rather than creating a new workbook and using VBA to set the header values???

Comment: The problem is only the first workbook is mine and all of the second is written and embedded in a v complex access/excel system...noone i have spoken to can understand why the ExportOpenlinkDeals code fails to create a new workbook when called from another macro...

Comment: It sounds like **both** `Workbook1` AND `Workbook2` contain the ExportOpenLInkDeals sub -- is that correct?  If so, are you sure you're calling the right one? It sounds like you are maybe calling the wrong one.

Comment: No only Workbook 2 contains ExportOpenlinkDeals - the Hedge sub in Workbook 1 calls ExportOpenlinkDeals from Workbook 2

Answer (score 0):

OK well here is what I can tell you based on my attempt to replicate your problem.

I created two files: workbook1.xlsm and workbook2.xlsm

**In workbook1, I have the following code in a standard module, Module1**

This code opens the workbook2 and calls the `ExportOpenLinkDeals` procedure *from* workbook2.

```
Sub Hedge()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("c:\users\david_zemens\desktop\workbook2.xlsm")

Application.Run wb2.Name & "!ExportOpenLinkDeals"

End Sub
```

**In workbook2, I have the following code in a standard module, Module1**

This is the `ExportOpenLinkDeals` procedure called from workbook1.  This procedure also calls your `SetOpenLinkHeader` which is also in workbook2.

```
Sub ExportOpenLinkDeals()
Dim objWbk As Workbook
Dim objWbkOut As Workbook
Dim objWS As Worksheet
Dim objWSOut As Worksheet

    Set objWbk = ThisWorkbook  '## Workbook2
    Set objWS = objWbk.Worksheets(3)

    Set objWbkOut = Application.Workbooks.Add
    Set objWSOut = objWbkOut.Worksheets(1)

    SetOpenLinkHeader objWSOut
End Sub
Private Sub SetOpenLinkHeader(objWS As Worksheet)
With objWS
    MsgBox IIF(.Parent.Name=ThisWorkbook.Name, "error!", "success!")
    .Range("A1").Value2 = "Type"
    .Range("B1").Value2 = "Trader id"
    .Range("C1").Value2 = "Trader location"
    .Range("D1").Value2 = "Chain"
    .Range("E1").Value2 = "Buy/sell"
    .Range("F1").Value2 = "Grade"
    .Range("G1").Value2 = "Internal Legal entity"
    .Range("H1").Value2 = "Month"
    .Range("I1").Value2 = "Year"
    .Range("J1").Value2 = "Put/Call"
    .Range("K1").Value2 = "Strike"
    .Range("L1").Value2 = "Quantity Lots Required"
    .Range("M1").Value2 = "Order type"
    .Range("N1").Value2 = "Executing broker"
    .Range("O1").Value2 = "Clearing broker"
    .Range("P1").Value2 = "Quantity Lots Filled"
    .Range("Q1").Value2 = "Price"
    .Range("R1").Value2 = "Electronic market flag"
    .Range("S1").Value2 = "EFP Deal Reference"
    .Range("T1").Value2 = "External legal entity"
    .Range("U1").Value2 = "Cross Entity Flag"
    .Range("V1").Value2 = "Balmo Day"
    .Range("W1").Value2 = "Trad Date"
    .Range("X1").Value2 = "UTI"
End With
End Sub
```

This code works as expected, and the MsgBox informs me that a new book has been added and the header row data has been written in *that* new workbook.

This code works. **How does it differ from your implementation?**  Answer that, and you will find your problem.

Comment: I can find absolutely no difference to my implementation bar slight referencing differences. Even when I make the referencing identical i get an error pop up...this is s frustrating! Thanks for the attempt.