# Excel VBA - Run Macro / Open another file / Run that files macro / Save & Close

Tags: vba, excel

This is what I'm trying to do.

- Run macro in file x
- File x macro opens file y
- Then calls file y's macro
- File y's macro runs
- File y closes

Currently, I'm getting as far as opening file y from file x's macro, but the macro ends once file y is open and doesn't step through past opening.

I had a look and attempted using info from this thread [Run excel macro on multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708395/run-excel-macro-on-multiple-files), but it didn't help.

Appreciate any help anyone can offer.

Here is the part of my code it gets to before ending. This opens file y, but ends the macro;

```
Workbooks.Open (MyPath & FileY & ".xls")
```

I want the macro to then do this;

```
ActiveWorkbook.Application.Run FileYsMacro
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the full section of code?  It *should* continue after opening the workbook. [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: How are you running the first macro? If it's via shortcut key combination involving the Shift key, try one that doesn't use Shift.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390156/code-error-when-called-from-another-workbook/24414952#24414952

Comment: Use `Application.Run FileY & "!MacroName"`

Comment: @chrisberry86 Welcome to the site. It's not snobbery. this site is different than most. Take a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) and this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get the most out of using this site. The downvotes help others looking for similar help know if this is a good question. Don't get mad, edit the question to be more clear. (also, calling people snobs is not likely to get you more sympathy, instead could get you banned)

Comment: And full disclosure. I've flagged your snob comment as 'rude or offensive'. Keep it nice!

Comment: Fair enough, I understand. A little demotivating considering the effort, but absolutely get why everything is done how it is on the site now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use ActiveWorkbook. Use:

```
 Workbooks("WorkbookName").Application.Run
```