# Run a macro in a workbook object from another macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a macro that lives in workbook B from within a macro in workbook A.

I was looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34211496/run-a-macro-from-another-workbook). However, the difference is that my workbook is a workbook object...

```
'Declare workbook objects   
Dim AssociateTemplateFile As Workbook  
Dim AssociateTemplateName As String  
Set AssociateTemplateFile = Workbooks.Open(RootPath & AssociateTemplateName)
```

This means I loose the ability to encase the name within ' ':

```
Application.Run "'AssociateTemplateFile' !AddDataValidation"
```

Doesn't work. I tried several iterations, with the variable, the file, but nothing seems to be working.

Any suggestions on how to get this going? I can always force run the macro to run when the other workbook is open, but I prefer to have the control in the main file if possible...

Comment: `Application.Run "'" & AssociateTemplateFile & "'!AddDataValidation"`? it was in the second answer BTW.

Comment: Hey Scott! Thank you so much. Completely missed that part

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run a Macro from Another Workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34211496/run-a-macro-from-another-workbook)