Applikation. Run runtime error loading macro from other workbook
I have a problem with running a vba macro from another Excel workbook.
I have an Excel workbook called Test.xlsx. From this workbook, I am using a macro called test. This should open a workbook called xxx_yyy.xlsm. From the workbook xxx_yyy.xlsm, I would like to use the macros Makro1, Makro2, Makro3.
Therefore I wrote the code shown here.
But with the command line Application.Run for makro1, I get a runtime error, because the macro is either not available or macro is deactivated. If I'm going to outline the command line for Makro1 and start with Makro2, everything runs fine.
I don't know why I'm getting this runtime error. Does anyone have an idea?
Sub test()

    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "C:\User\Desktop\xxx_yyy.xlsm", _
        UpdateLinks:=0
    
    Workbooks("xxx_yyy.xlsm").Activate
    
    Application.Run "'xxx_yyy.xlsm'!Makro1"
    Application.Run "'xxx_yyy.xlsm'!Makro2"
    Application.Run "'xxx_yyy.xlsm'!Makro3"

End Sub



Look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34211496/run-a-macro-from-another-workbook  I think you need to fully qualify your Application.Run line w/the workbook that has the macro

Are the 3 macros all in a regular code module and are they all Public ?
